# Adding classes to checked boxes in simple_form association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

How would I go with adding an additional 'checked-class' (server-side) for a checkbox that is selected with this kind of code:

```
= f.association :tags, as: :check_boxes, item_wrapper_class: 'default-class', 
include_blank: false, label: "Categories"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is an easy way to do it, but I would suggest that you use CSS pseudo-class :checked if you want to style it

```
.default-class input:checked {
  // any style
}
```

or you can get it with jQuery with

```
$(".default-class input:checked")
```

I know this is not exactly what you are looking for, but since I couldn't find you the best solution I though this could do some help